# Prevent google from indexing my pages as ssl

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have my own domain (such as mysite.com) but im on a shared server, thus my ssl is shared too. So if i need a page to be on SSL i have to access it by using my host SSL URL (something like https://myhostssl.com/~mysite-com/whateverpage.html). The problem is that every document on my root directory becomes SSL if accessed that way and Google is indexing many of my pages with the SSL URL. And since the SSL domain is different than mine, it interprets them as if they were from a completely different site which has a negative effect on my Google rank performance.

So i wonder if its possible to block access to those pages if accessed from the SSL URL, with an htaccess or a robots.txt file and how to do it. I tried with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/no-ssl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With that i was trying to prevent SSL access to all the documents in the no-ssl directory but it didnt work. I guess because the SSL URL is different.

Could you please give me a hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you have access to the root, so I think a robots.txt solution is out of the question, unless your host will add a `Disallow:` directive to https://myhostssl.com/robots.txt

Instead of trying to solve the problem with .htaccess, you might want to consider just using a [rel=canonical tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394). So even though the URL is being passed through your host's SSL domain, the pages being crawled will still canonicalize to your domain. And since `rel=canonical`s are supported cross domain, you shouldn't see any of the SSL domains showing up after the pages have been re-crawled.

Additionally, if your code base is serving a different page / template when it detects an SSL request, you can always add a `meta` tag or `X-Robots-Tag` in the HTTP Headers with a directive of `noindex`. This will tell the engines not to list the contents of the page on the given URL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I just need to put something like this <link rel="canonical" href="https://myhostssl.com/~mysite-com/"> within the <head> of all the pages inside my no-ssl folder?

Comment: @CainNuke You'll probably want to do `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.yoursite.com/uri-path/" />` This way when Google see the pages on https://myhostssl.com they'll attribute all the link value to www.yoursite.com and not your host's site.